# Predict in R gives probabilities or some score?

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost, predict

I am new to R and trying to build xgboost model , I am able to get prediction in pred variable

```
X_train <- train_list$X
X_test <- test_list$X

X_Train <- as(X_train, "dgCMatrix")



xgb <- xgboost(data = X_train, 
               label = y_train, 
               eta = 0.9,
               max_depth = 3, 
               nround=10, 
               subsample = 0.3,      
               colsample_bytree = 0.1,  
               seed = 1,
               eval_metric = "auc",
               objective = "binary:logistic",
               #num_class = 2,
               booster = 'gbtree',  
               max_delta_step = 1,    
               scale_pos_weight=2,   
               gamma=5 ,                  
               min_child_weight = 2    
)


pred <- predict(xgb, X_test)
```

I would like to know pred is probability or score, I feel the prediction are probabilities but not sure.

If some one can clear by doubt on this and if it is not probabilities then what it is ?

Answer (score 0):

In a binary / 2-class problem, if one of the classes (positive) = 1, and the other class (negative) = 0, your predictions that you calculate using your trained model (via `predict()`) will fall somewhere between 0 and 1. The probability that a predicted value is 1 (positive class) or 0 (negative class) is the absolute difference from 0.5, and you typically transform the predictions so that <0.5 becomes '0' (negative) and >0.5 becomes '1' (positive). This is all explained in detail in the docs: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/R-package/xgboostPresentation.html#perform-the-prediction